# How to make tridiagonal matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

How I create matrix  below from vector [1 2 3 4 5]

```
1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 0 0
3 2 1 0 0
4 3 2 1 0
5 4 3 2 1
0 5 4 3 2
0 0 5 4 3
0 0 0 5 4
0 0 0 0 5
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not tridiagonal, but a variant of pentadiagonal matrix. You can use diag, or sparse, or spdiags, all of which could build it. You could read my [blktridiag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10603) code, as found on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), to learn how I build such a matrix efficiently.

But perhaps the simplest solution is to recognize that your matrix is of a special form, a toeplitz matrix.

```
>> toeplitz([1:5,zeros(1,4)]',[1, zeros(1,4)])
ans =
     1     0     0     0     0
     2     1     0     0     0
     3     2     1     0     0
     4     3     2     1     0
     5     4     3     2     1
     0     5     4     3     2
     0     0     5     4     3
     0     0     0     5     4
     0     0     0     0     5
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you may find `diag(v,n)` and `convmtx(v)` useful. In your case

```
 convmtx([1,2,3,4,5],5)
```

Produces:

```
 1     2     3     4     5     0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3     4     5     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3     4     5     0     0
 0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     0
 0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diag.html

Example:

```
diag(-m:m)+diag(ones(2*m,1),1)+diag(ones(2*m,1),-1)
```

produces a tridiagonal matrix of order 2*m+1.