# Tridiagonal Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, toeplitz

Anyone know a quick efficient way in matlab to build the following square matrix

```
 1    -1     0     0     0     0
-1     2    -1     0     0     0
 0    -1     2    -1     0     0
 0     0    -1     2    -1     0
 0     0     0    -1     2    -1
 0     0     0     0    -1     1
```

Which has 2's on the diagonal except at first and last element of the diagonal and -1 on the two adjacent diagonals.

This was a 6x6 examples and I'd like to generate in Matlab nxn one as quick and as efficient as possible. I tried with the built-in function kron but couldn't get away with it.

Thansk a lot

Comment: Check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919779/how-to-make-tridiagonal-matrix-in-matlab).

Comment: @Naveh, that's not exactly the same request though...

Comment: I know, just thought it could be useful. It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option

```
function a = laplacianMatrix(n)

  a = toeplitz([2,-1,zeros(1,n-2)]);
  a([1,end]) = 1;

end
```

Whether this version or the version using `gallery` (see Sam Roberts' answer) is faster seems to depend on the size of the matrix. For small matrices (up to around `n = 200` on my machine) it is faster to use `toeplitz`. For larger matrices it is faster to use `gallery`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
function mymatrix = makemymatrix(n)

mymatrix = full(gallery('tridiag',n,-1,2,-1));
mymatrix([1,end]) = 1;
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = conv2(eye(6), [-1 2 -1],'same');
result([1 end]) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=6;

B=zeros(n);


for i=1:n

    for j=1:n
        B(1,1)=1;
        if i==j
        B(i,j)=2;
        elseif i==j+1
        B(i,j)=-1;
        elseif j==i+1
        B(i,j)=-1
        else
        B(i,j)=0;
        end
        B(n,n)=1;
    end

end;
 B
```